# Finding values where the content consists of allowed characters with optional x wildcards

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, find

I'm looking to filter rows with strings by a set of allowed characters so that the remaining rows only consist of the allowed characters. But it should also allow for a x number of wildcards.

Any character in the allowed list is allowed to be used unlimited times so **a** matches **aaaaaa**. The wildcards could be either 1 use per wildcard or unlimited per wildcard, preferably a solution for both situations.

So an example where the allowed characters are [a,b,c] with 0 to 2 wildcards:

|  | **DataSet** |  |  | **No Wildcards** |  |  | **1 Wildcard** |  |  | **2 Wildcards** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *id* | *value* |  | *id* | *value* |  | *id* | *value* |  | *id* | *value* |
| **1** | aabc |  | **1** | aabc |  | **1** | aabc |  | **1** | aabc |
| **2** | aabcd |  | **4** | cba |  | **2** | aabc**d** |  | **2** | aabc**d** |
| **3** | axbd |  |  |  |  | **4** | cba |  | **3** | a**x**b**d** |
| **4** | cba |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | **4** | cba |

The closest I've gotten is using regex for the 1 wildcard question, but that isn't scalable.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value ~* '^[abc -]*$|^[a-z][abc -]*$|^[abc -]*[a-z]$|^[abc -]*[a-z][abc -]*$'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regexp_split_to_table to split "value" into rows (characters).

Then exclude a,b,c and group rows by "id".

Just change the count value "0" for Wildcard.

```
select * from "table" where not exists (
    select id from (
        select id, count(*) as count from (
            select id, regexp_split_to_table(value,'') as r
            from "table"
        ) a
        where r ~ '^[^abc]$'
        group by id
    ) b where count > 0 and "table".id = b.id
)-- change the number ^ for Wildcard
```

**Result: No Wildcards**

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aabc |
| 4 | cba |

**1 Wildcard**

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aabc |
| 2 | aabcd |
| 4 | cba |

.

---

**Details**

From three to eight lines SQL above returns the table below.

| id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

This table's count column shows the number of
non-abc characters in "value" text.

Wildcard means non-abc characters so we just exclude
the ids using "not exists" operator.

We can control the number of Wildcards with the number after "count >" query text.